# Reactive/responsive RPG combat systems?

Tags: combat, game-recommendation

I grow tired of "Roll to hit, then do damage" in RPG combat.

As such I seek a system that gives the players and GM more freedom.

For example, this is what I'm looking for:

***Round 1***

**Player A** - Assumes a defensive stance while watching player B

**Player B** - Assumes an aggressive stance and charges player A, swinging their weapon (dice are rolled)

**Player A** - Gets a chance to respond, something like evade, parry, counter. Chooses to evade (dice are rolled)

**Player B** - After rolling is resolved, scores a glancing hit on player A, causing minor damage

***Round 2***

**Player A** - Maintains the defensive stance and attacks player B (dice are rolled)

**Player B** - Response choice is to counter (dice are rolled)

**Player A** - Counter fails and results in a hit against player B

**Player B** - Drops aggressive stance to a defensive one, swings against player A (dice are rolled)

**Player A** - Response choice of parry (dice are rolled)

**Player B** - Parry is extremely successful, forcing player A's weapon to the ground

***Round 3*** combat may continue or not

I assume **Aggressive** and **Defensive** stances might affect your dice count or modifiers

### Does any RPG system have a combat system that bears resemblance to this?

Comment: Such games do exist. However, recommendations of games that fit particular criteria was made off-topic a while ago (they just don't work well in our voting system). One of these [RPG discussion forum suggestions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) could handle such a question though. You might also wish to browse our [old questions tagged with \[game-recommendation\] and \[combat\]](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation+combat), which have some recommendation requests that are similar to this one.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. There are [literally thousands](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1475/4398) of RPGs, and many of them are able to produce gameplay experiences like you're describing--others defy the whole "attack/defend" paradigm in favour of something very different for combat. You may find the [chat] a helpful place to discuss what you're looking for and how to get it.